# setState doesn't re-render react functional component

Tags: reactjs, setstate, react-leaflet

I am getting user's location and setting it as the new state at "onSuccess" function,
the component doesn't re-render.
After checking a lot i have seen that react doesn't see it as a change of state because it is an array in that case and it doesn't pass react's "equality" check as a state that was changed.
With that, nothing that i have tried has worked. any ideas?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";

export default function Map() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState([52.234, 13.413]);

  const onSuccess = (position) => {
    let userLocation = [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude];
    setLocation([...userLocation]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!("geolocation" in navigator)) {
      alert("no Geolocation available");
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess);
  }, []);
  console.log(location);
  return (
    <>
      <MapContainer
        className="leaflet-map"
        center={location}
        zoom={11}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: your `console.log` should be inside a `useEffect`. it works actually

Comment: i put console.log there just to see that the state changes, which does happen, but it doesn't re-render

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `MapContainer` does not recenter after mounting even if the `center` prop is changed as mentioned in the docs:

https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map

> Except for its children, MapContainer props are immutable: changing them after they have been set a first time will have no effect on the Map instance or its container.

You could force replacing the `MapContainer` by passing a `key` prop that you change whenever `location` changes, for example:

```
<MapContainer
    key={`${location[0]}-${location[1]}`}
```

Or investigating other options in `react-leaflet` such as `useMap` to get access to the Leaflet Map instance and calling `map.setView(...)` https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-setview

Comment: ok that was it, wow thanks!! 
Do you think it makes sense to use react-leaflet and not just normal leaflet.js? it seems quite complicated and the documentation isn't that great

Comment: @TomerRajuan No problem, react-leaflet might still be good to handle the mounting and unmounting of Leaflet. I've added another option to my answer instead of replacing `MapContainer` (which is not great for animations, performance etc.). Using something like `useMap` to get the Leaflet Map instance and you can use the Leaflet Map API, or another option is to delay rendering of the map until you have the final location you want to center on.

Comment: This worked for me, strange way to work for this component

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to confirm that `onSuccess` is called at all? It may be that `getCurrentPosition` is running into an error, so calling it with two arguments would be good:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

You should also include `onSuccess` in the `useEffect` dependencies.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!("geolocation" in navigator)) {
      alert("no Geolocation available");
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess);
  }, [onSuccess]);
```

And to prevent multiple calls to `getCurrentPosition` due to `onSuccess` changing, you should also `useCallback` with the dependency on `setLocation`:

```
  const onSuccess = useCallback((position) => {
    let userLocation = [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude];
    setLocation([...userLocation]);
  }, [setLocation]);
```

Comment: why would you need to add `onSuccess` as dependency if you want to execute that code only on mount?

Comment: It's not necessary, but I think it is recommended and the React hooks linter will likely warn that the `useEffect` is missing dependencies if it's not included. Having `onSuccess` be a callback will mean that it does not change, so the effect will still only run on mount, too.

Comment: @Ric thank you however it still doesn't re-render. the onSuccess is called and i can also console.log the change of "location" in state. I think it has to do that React checks the state and compares the array to be still an array so doesn't see it as if state changed..